# Selenium: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome' (Change desktop to mobile)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

how can I change desktop chrome to mobile?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
mobile_emulation = {

    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },

    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
```

All I want to do is visit site as desktop, then - mobile.

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

Comment: Line 16 of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
mobile_emulation = {
"deviceName": "iPad"
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```